# How to put Prometheus behind Envoy front-proxy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, envoyproxy

I'm trying to put Envoy in front of our Prometheus docker container, but haven't been able to successfully get the routing to work properly. I get the error:

"upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: overflow "

I've already tried manipulating the "git clone https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy" repository in the example/front-proxy config and changed the ports around in the config.

Docker-Compose File

```
services:

  front-envoy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-frontenvoy
    volumes:
      - ./front-envoy.yaml:/etc/front-envoy.yaml
    networks:
      - envoymesh
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "8001"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "8001:8001"

  prom1:
    container_name: prom
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./service-envoy.yaml:/etc/service-envoy.yaml
    networks:
      envoymesh:
        aliases:
          - prom1
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=1
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"

networks:
  envoymesh: {}
```

Front-Envoy.yaml

```
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/prom/1"
                route:
                  cluster: prom1
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: prom1
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: prom1
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 0.0.0.0
                port_value: 80
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
```

service-envoy.yaml

```
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: service
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/prom"
                route:
                  cluster: local_service
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: local_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: local_service
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 0.0.0.0
                port_value: 9090
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8081
```

I'd like to be able to go to localhost:8000/prom/1 and be routed to the Prometheus docker container

Comment: My reading of your `Front-Envoy.yaml` leads me to believe that you're just routing traffic back to the same envoy instance in a loop. Further there isn't going to be an envoy running as a side-car in the `prom/prometheus` image to use your provided `service-envoy.yaml`. Do you need/want this to work via a side car?